# distinguishing qrcode url parameters from those of the api url

Tags: javascript, api, qr-code

I want to generate a qr code with multiple pre-filled values. But only the first value seems to be encoded into the generated qr code. I guess because it's assuming parameters after the first belong to the api url..

Can anyone help me here?

```
.src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=" 
+ "https://google.com/?" + "field1=" + var1 + "&" + "field2=" + var2
```

I've looked online without luck - perhaps because I don't know how to describe the problem. (note that google.com is jut a placeholder url, and not the one i'm using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URL you are trying to pass to `data` contains `/`, `?` and `&` you have to encode it. For instance, the browser wouldn't know whether to pass `field2` to the main URL or to the `data` URL. To encode the URL being passed to `data`:

```
const url = "https://google.com/?" + "field1=" + var1 + "&" + "field2=" + var2
const src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=" + encodeURIComponent(url)
```

On an unrelated note, consider using template string to make your code more readable:

```
const url = `https://google.com/?field1=${var1}&field2=${var2}`
const src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks Enve. Something obvious if you know it I guess but a battle otherwise.